# Smooth animation on pure js css for a training site

Tags: javascript, html, css

please tell me, otherwise I forgot. How can I make a smooth slide transition animation? Here is js and css code
i know teg anitame, transform, is not work
this shelter for pets site, and sencion for html, css, js slider
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7sMh.jpg)

```
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

let prev = document.getElementById("prev");
let next = document.getElementById("next");

next.addEventListener("click", function () {
  showSlides((slideIndex += 1));
  makeTimer(); 
});

prev.addEventListener("click", function () {
  showSlides((slideIndex -= 1));
  makeTimer(); 
});

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myslide");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }

  for (let slide of slides) {
    slide.style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "flex";

}
let timer = 0;
makeTimer(); // интервал
function makeTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(function () {
    slideIndex++;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
  }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Please read about [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). It is one of the best way to make smooth animation on web

Comment: Use the CSS [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property to *smoothly* animate changes in styles. Do note that the `display` property is not animatable. Use `opacity` instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.